# Is it possible to run match servers on Kubernetes for a Real Time Multiplayer game?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, multiplayer

I can't seem to find any resources online on people doing this, yet it would seem to be possible through the use of StatefulSet (?). I can imagine that whenever a Match is made a Pod would be scheduled and when the Match is over it would be removed.

There's a bunch of other questions such as: How does one manage upgrades? One cannot simply shutdown a match in progress.

Very curious to hear how this should be tackled.

**Update:** The only state needed for Match servers would be in-memory. It would keep track of the players on that Match, the team composition, etc. This could easily be passed in through Env variables. Matches would typically last between 5-20 minutes and the instance/Pod would be torn down once the Match ends.

Comment: Can you give more details on this? Is there any state needed by match servers?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Buchi, I've updated my post.

Comment: What happens if a pod/container crashes in the middle of a match? Would you want to restart the match from beginning or from the point where it was before the crash?

Comment: @Buchi In the unfortunate event a Pod crashes, the match would be canceled and a new match would be booted in a new Pod.

Answer (score 0):

I think Daemon Sets would fit, https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/daemons/

Comment: Hey Michael, how exactly do you think Daemon Sets would fit?

Comment: Sorry. You are right it would not help. So for this case I wold recommend to write a custom controller or operator. here is example: https://github.com/coreos/etcd-operator. Introduction to operators: https://coreos.com/blog/introducing-operators.html